# How can I reload free-jqgrid with data inside a json object?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

After constructing a free-jqgrid how can I reload this grid with data of a JSON object ?

Comment: Could you describe more detailed and more clear your question? Which `datatype` you use? What you mean under JSON object? Do you mean just array of items? JSON in the format of representing/encoding object as a string. Thus one can say only JSON string, but not JSON object. One uses JSON strings typically for sending objects over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Would that be by using GridUnload() to unload the grid and then reconstruct the grid like it was created at first place ?

Comment: Is it the answer on your question or a new question?